# Is it possible to loop the searching and saving of result output from spocc() in R?

Tags: r

I have an assignment that requires me to search for species occurrence data points that occur within a region (SEA). I have a list of 49 shark species to search for and I'm trying to write a code in R to automate things.

I found a package that enables the searching of species occurrence data "spocc" package, that has the function `occ()` within. The results of the `occ()` function is a large list containing the metadata and the occurrence data. So in order to access the data rows that I want, I will need to extract them.

My code, which is written to search for one species, currently looks like this:

```
df <- occ(query = "hammerhead shark", from = c('gbif'), limit = 3))
          
df_gbif <- df$gbif$data$hammerhead_shark %>%
  coord_impossible(., lat ='latitude', lon = 'longitude', drop = TRUE) %>%
  coord_unlikely(., lat ='latitude', lon = 'longitude', drop = TRUE) %>%
  filter(., latitude < 31.2 &  latitude > -12.4) %>%
  filter(., longitude > 89 & longitude < 153)
    
write.xlsx(df_gbif, file = "hammerhead_shark.xlsx")
```

I would like to know if there is a way to loop this whole process: to search for species occurrence data points of 49 species, extract relevant results and save the results in excel files.

Answer (score 1):

probably a bit late but you could modify this to loop over your 49 species.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(spocc)

# Species to serche for
species<- data.frame(species=c("Agrilus planipennis", "Anopheles gambiae"))

# empty data frame
df<- data.frame(name=NA, longitude=NA, latitude=NA)

# species to loop over 
sp_list<- unique(species$species)

for (i in sp_list){

out<-spocc::occ(query=i , from="gbif", has_coords = T, limit=50000)

out_df<-spocc::occ2df(out)

out_df <- dplyr::select(out_df, name, longitude, latitude)

complete<-dplyr::bind_rows(df, out_df) %>% na.omit()
}

head(complete)
```